# How to calculate [AC]?

Tags: geometry

This might sound very noob but what is the equation to calculate the *unknown* distance `[AC]` *given* all values of the rest?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways. You could use the law of cosines:
$$(AC)^2 = (AB)^2 + (BC)^2 - 2(AB)(BC)\cos(b)$$
as well as the law of sines
$$\frac{AC}{\sin(b)} = \frac{BC}{\sin(a)} = \frac{AB}{\sin(c)}$$
Both of these work for any triangle.

Comment: Excellent match of what I am looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hint:-

Use sine rule-

$$\frac{a}{\sin A}=\frac{b}{\sin B}=\frac{c}{\sin C}$$

where $A,B,C$ are the angles of the triangle and $a,b,c$ are respectively the sides opposite to them.

[image]